# Removing Child table from div

Tags: javascript, html

For learning, i am writing html code and js script for practise.
Here i want to generate a new table everytime i click on Generate button. But since i have used AppendChild, its appending the table on every click. I have tried addchild(tbl1) and similar ways but its not working. Can you pls point where i am doing wrong.

```
function drawTable() {
    // get the reference for the body
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');

    // creates a <table> element
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");

    // creating rows
    for (var r = 0; r < totalRows; r++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

     // create cells in row
         for (var c = 0; c < cellsInRow; c++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
    getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }           

tbl.appendChild(row); // add the row to the end of the table body
    }
    div1.appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: Add this code after getting div1. while (div1.firstChild) {div1.removeChild(div1.firstChild);};

Comment: You want to replace the existing table with the new table?

Comment: You could add `div1.innerHTML = ""` after the line `var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/28qS6/)